# C# WPF dispose of Image object

Tags: c#, wpf, image, graphics, gdi

I capture the screen and then save the image data to a memory stream so I can set it into a BitmapImage object.

```
bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)sel.rectSelectedArea.Width, (int)sel.rectSelectedArea.Height);
bounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)sel.rectSelectedArea.X, (int)sel.rectSelectedArea.Y, (int)sel.rectSelectedArea.Width, (int)sel.rectSelectedArea.Height);

using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    g.CopyFromScreen(new System.Drawing.Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bounds.Size);

ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Position = 0;

frames.Add(new BitmapImage());
frames.Last().BeginInit();
frames.Last().StreamSource = ms;
frames.Last().EndInit();
frames.Last().Freeze();
```

Then when I need to show that frame to the user. I set the selected frame as the Source to the Image object.

```
imgExample.Source = frames[targetFrame];
```

The issue is when I show the user another frame. The previous frame remains in memory so after about 200 frames, it racks up 3-600,000 K of memory that it never releases.

Is there a method for having the imgExample (Image object) release the memory instantly?
Or is there a method for overwriting the same memory instead of creating new objects for all frames.

Comment: I love the way you're bringing dinosaur `System.Drawing` stuff into WPF.

Comment: You could try a WriteableBitmap - those are easy to update as often as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
bmp.Dispose();
bmp = null;
```

or

```
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: I need to retain the BMP for showing the frames, but I need it to not always be in memory when it is not displayed.

Comment: So, you want to keep the BMP... but not in memory? Say, by writing it to disk?